# Помогите переписать формулу с помощью цикла while

Tags: c, for, while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define x1 0.75
#define x2 0.012
#define dx -0.092
#define a 2.65
#define b 1.48
int main()
{
    float x, k;
    for(x=x1;x>x2;x+=dx) {
    k=(sin(exp(1)*pow(x,2)))/sqrt(a+b*(x*x*x));
    printf("\nk=%f x=%f",k,x);
    }
}
```

Мне нужно переписать этот код с помощью цикла while, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define x1 0.75
#define x2 0.012
#define dx -0.092
#define a 2.65
#define b 1.48
int main() {
    double x = x1;

    while (x > x2) {
        printf("\nk=%lf x=%lf",
               (sin(exp(1)*pow(x, 2)))
               / sqrt(a + b * (x * x * x)), x);
        x += dx;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция while:

```
while <УСЛОВИЕ> do {
 действие
 счетчик
}
```

На картинке указано (прошу прощения за курицелапость на картинке) где нач.знач, где условие, где счетчик и где действие. Попытайтесь. Покажите что получится. Потом сформулируйте вопрос, что именно не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define x1 0.75
#define x2 0.012
#define dx -0.092
#define a 2.65
#define b 1.48
int main()
{
    float x, k;
    while (x=x1;x>x2) do {
    k=(sin(exp(1)*pow(x,2)))/sqrt(a+b*(x*x*x));
    printf("\nk=%f x=%f",k,x);
    x+=dx;
    }
}  Не получилось(

Comment: Начальное значение до цикла надо устанавливать. Например: < int x = 0; > Потом Цикл.  (Цикл while можно реализовать с параметром, с предусловием и постусловием.) Раз взяли счетчик, значит while с параметром будет. Соответственно указываете условие выполнения цикла. Например пока " x<10 " вы выполняете блок действий. И не забудьте изменять параметр "X" внутри тело цикла. Иначе зациклится. Более подробно почитайте: <https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-loops/>